# How to sort array of data objects in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple way to sort an array of data pulled from the server in React. The implementation I'm using shown below is probably not the best way to go about it, but I feel it should be working, but is not. It seems the sorting function is never being called, and the data is being displayed in the default order that it comes in from the server.

I'm trying to make a simple `orderByRecent` function reverse the order of the data, which is returned in chronological order. I know there are ways to accomplish this server-side but this is just an experiment for more complex client-side sorting.

sorting function:

```
orderByDate: (threads) => {
    return threads.sort((a, b) => {
        return Date.parse(a.date) > Date.parse(b.date)
    })
},
```

Feed.js:

```
class ThreadList extends Component {
  render() {
    var threadNodes, sortedThreadNodes
    if (this.props.data) {
      var sorted = this.props.sortFunc(this.props.data)
      var threadNodes = sorted.map(function (thread) {
        return (
          <Thread victim={ thread.victim } 
                  date={ thread.date }
                  author={ thread.author } 
                  ct={ thread.included.length }
                  likes={ thread.likes } 
                  dislikes={ thread.dislikes }
                  id={ thread._id}
                  key={ thread._id }>
            { thread.text }
          </Thread>
        )
      })
    }
    return (
      <div className="threadList">
        { threadNodes }
      </div>
      )
  }
}

var ThreadsBox = React.createClass({
  handleThreadSubmit: function (thread) {
    var threads = this.props.feed
    var newThreads = threads.concat([thread])
    this.setState({feed: newThreads})
    $.ajax({
      url: config.apiUrl + 'threads',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: thread,
      xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
      success: function (data) {
        // this.setState({feed: feed})
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        this.setState({data: threads})
        console.log(this.url, status, err.toString())
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  // Feed nav buttons default to order by date
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {feed: [], sortFunc: helpers.orderByDate}
  },

  changeState: function (state, value) {
    this.setState({[state]: value})
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
    <div className="threadsBox">
      <ThreadForm friends={this.props.friends}
                  onThreadSubmit={ this.handleThreadSubmit }/>
      <div className="feedNav">
        <NavButtonList divId={"feedNav"}
                       eventFunc={this.changeState} 
                       state={"sortFunc"} 
                       buttons={buttonObs.mainNavButtons} />
      </div>
      <ThreadList data={ this.props.feed }
                  sortFunc={ this.state.sortFunc } />

    </div>
    )
  }
})


module.exports = ThreadsBox
```

Comment: Note that the function you pass to .sort() is *not* supposed to return a boolean.

Comment: @nnnnnn Ah, that was it! I changed the function to return either 1 or -1, and it works.

Comment: Cool. Or it should return 0 if the two values are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach.

Keep your threads in an object that maps `threadId` to the actual `Thread` data.

Keep a separate array that has the `threadId`s in the order that you want to sort them. When you sort your threads, you only change the ordering of the elements of the array.

When you want to sort the data differently, dispatch an action that will sort based on whatever constraints you have. Rendering the threads is as simple as performing a map over the array and getting the proper thread.

Comment: What would be the purpose of keeping an object and an array of the data, instead of just sorting the array? Thanks

Comment: Allows for more extensible functionality: search and filtering in particular. Search runs an HTTP request and grabs data: any data you receive either exists in your store, or it doesn't. You can run into the problem of having multiple sources of truth: storing all the threads in one place eliminates this. To ensure that is this is maintained, you only keep references of the the ids that you want to display.